How to properly set up Firebase for unit testing inside Flutter?
I would like to start writing tests for my Flutter project. For some reason writing tests in Flutter is really hard for me. I already have methods that are working on when I run flutter normally, but when I try to test the same methods using test, they aren't working as expected, I'm always getting some errors.
Could someone show me how to set up Firebase for testing, I would appreciate if someone could just give me a simple example of storing anything on my Firebase.
If someone wants to know what I've tried, here it is:
This is the Repository that I wanted to test:
class RoleRepository {

  final CollectionReference _rolesCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Role');

  Future<void> createRole(RoleModel role) async {
    await _rolesCollection.add(role.toMap());
  }

   ...
}

This is the test:
void main() async{
    late RoleServiceImpl roleService;
    late MockRoleRepository mockRoleRepository;

   setUpAll(() async {
      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      mockRoleRepository = MockRoleRepository();
      roleService = RoleServiceImpl();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
    });

  group('Role Tests', () {
    
    test('createRole()', () async {
      final role = RoleModel(role: 'Admin', user_id: 'user1');

      await roleService.createRole(role);

      verify(mockRoleRepository.createRole(role)).called(1);
    });
  }
}

When I run the test I get:
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart 195:5  
package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart 79:41                                                   
package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart 33:21                                                FirebaseFirestore.instance
package:bee/Repository/RoleRepository.dart 6:66                                                 new RoleRepository
package:bee/Service/Impl/RoleServiceImpl.dart 6:45                                              new RoleServiceImpl
test\role_test.dart 20:21                                                                       main.<fn>.<fn>
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()MethodChannelFirebase.appFirebase.app

Sometimes this:
Firebase initialization failed: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

As the error says the Firebase isn't set up properly but the same code works in main.dart when I run the app inside my web or android:
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);

I've tried creating Mocks as well, here is how I generated them: (but that also didn't work)
import 'package:bee/Repository/RoleRepository.dart';
import 'package:bee/Service/Impl/RoleServiceImpl.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

(
  [
    RoleRepository,
    RoleServiceImpl,
  ],
  customMocks: [MockSpec<http.Client>(as: #MockHttpClient)],
)
void main(){

}

